# I would like to know how to display the services

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am currently working on a `bluetooth` chip and I would like to display its features.

I am trying the method `getService();` but this one returned to me `null`

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback =
        new BluetoothGattCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                String intentAction;
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                    mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                    broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                            mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.UUID_Address)));


                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                    mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                    Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                    broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                }
            }
        };
```

I would like to show in the logs the list of characteristics.
thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You're receiving `null` from `BluetoothGatt#getServices()` because [BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()) is an asynchronous call. The documentation says we will get the list of services inside overriden [BluetoothGattCallback#onServicesDiscovered()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onServicesDiscovered(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int)) method.

Comment: you have to wait till services are discovered before getting a service probably

Comment: I do not understand well, I'm just starting the Android.